# (Julia) What is the difference between explicitly passing an array into a function, and calling that array from within an argument-less function?

Tags: julia

Consider the following:

```
let
    test = [1,2,3]
    
    function testf(test)
        display(test)
        test = "blah"
        display(test)
        end#function
    
    testf(test); display(test)
end
```

Above I explicitly passed array `test` into `testf(test)`, then reassigned `test` to a string; but this does not change the global value of test. The output for me (using Julia 1.4.1) is:

```
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

"blah"

3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
```

Now consider:

```
let
    test = [1,2,3]
    
    function testf()
        display(test)
        test = "blah"
        display(test)
        end#function
    
    testf(); display(test)
end
```

Where here I have not explicitly passed `test` as an arg. The output:

```
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

"blah"

"blah"
```

Such that globally-scoped `test` has been reassigned to the string.

From the difference b/w these two cases, I get the sense that explicit function arguments are copied into a local variable of the same name but different scope. In other words, I'm guessing the first case is identical to:

```
let
    test = [1,2,3]
    
    function testf()
        test_copy = copy(test)
        display(test===test_copy) # output: false (Julia 1.4.1)
        display(test_copy)
        test_copy = "blah"
        display(test_copy)
        end#function
    
    testf(); display(test)
end
```

which I find produces the same output as case #1. Is this the difference b/w these two cases? And are my case #1 and #3 essentially identical, or are there differences not made obvious by this particular example?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't an answer. But a suggestion to upgrade to a newer Julia version. As the Red Queen said to Alice: *it takes all the running you can do, to keep in the same place*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at the second case first:

```
let
    test = [1,2,3]
    
    function testf()
        display(test)
        test = "blah"
        display(test)
        end#function
    
    testf(); display(test)
end
```

Here there is a single `test` variable that is local to the `let` block. The same local variable is visible in the body of `testf` and is assigned when `test = "blah"` is evaluated. When `display(test)` is called `test` therefore has the value `"blah"`.

Now, let's look at the first case:

```
let
    test = [1,2,3]
    
    function testf(test)
        display(test)
        test = "blah"
        display(test)
        end#function
    
    testf(test); display(test)
end
```

Here there are two distinct local variables named `test`:

1. The variable in the `let` block
2. The argument to the `testf` function

Since these are distinct local variables (the latter "shadows" the former), assigning to one does not affect the other—that's the whole point of scope: when `test = "blah"` happens inside `testf`, it reassigns the `test` variable that is local to `testf` but has no effect on the `test` variable that is local to the `let` block. When `display(test)` is called at the end, it doesn't matter that the `test` variable in `testf` has been chaanged because the call to `display(test)` occurs outside of the scope of `testf`.

Comment: Hey thanks! Fantastic -- that is what I intuited. Am I correct in thinking that this "shadow" is simply a function-local copy (or perhaps deepcopy) of the original `test`?

Comment: The `test` inside `testf` is not a copy. It is just a new reference to the same array. You can modify the array by e.g. `test[1] = 42` inside `testf`, and it will be visible outside.

Comment: Right, what @SimenGaure said: having two variables referencing the same object does not copy, but it does mean that because they are different variables, assigning to one variable does not affect what the other variable refers to. Assignment and argument passing never creates a copy of any object in Julia. This is similar in many languages including Python, Lisp and Java. If, on the other hand, you were to mutate the object that the two variables refer to, that change would be visible through both as there is only one object.